# DiscretizeGraphics issues with transformations

Tags: graphics, bugs, regions, mesh, geometric-transform

I noticed `DiscretizeGraphics` does not work correctly with transformed `Graphics` such as

```
Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], 30°]]
```

[image: graphics1]

Both using `Rotate` and `GeometricTransformation` together with `RotationTransform` yield `EmptyRegion[2]` when `DiscretizeGraphics` is used.

```
Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], 30°]] // DiscretizeGraphics   
(* EmptyRegion[2] *)

GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[], 
RotationTransform[30°]]] // Graphics // DiscretizeGraphics
(* EmptyRegion[2] *)
```

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a four possibilities. Two of them are due to @JM's comments. (Thanks!) All of them are based on the fact that `Rectangle[]` can be used as a geometric region as well as a graphics primitive, and they all use `TransformedRegion` to get the rotation rather than `GeometricTransformation`, `RotationTransform` or `Rotate`.

Define the rotated rectangle as a region:

```
reg = TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], RotationTransform[π/6]]

(* Parallelogram[{0, 0}, {{-(1/2), Sqrt[3]/2}, {Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}}] *)
```

Then we can do

```
GraphicsRow[
 Through[{DiscretizeRegion, DiscretizeGraphics, 
          BoundaryDiscretizeRegion, BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics}@reg]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[]` and `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[]` can be used here too, of course.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for that. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the time being a workaround is using first `DiscretizeGraphics` and then transforming the region e.g.

```
Rectangle[] // DiscretizeGraphics //TransformedRegion[#, RotationTransform[30°]]&
```